# Как работает данный код?

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток, пожалуйста, объясните как работает данный код, ответ должен выйти - 2.

```js
const length = (str) => {
  return str.length;
}

const addDigits = (num) => {
  console.log(num);
  console.log("*************");
  let sum = 0;
  if (length(String(num)) == 1) {
    return num;
  }
  while (length(String(num)) > 1) {
    for (let i = 0; i <= length(String(num)) - 1; i++) {
      console.log(i, length(String(num)) - 1);
      sum = sum + Number(String(num)[i]);
      console.log(sum);
    }
    num = sum;
    sum = 0;
  }
  return num;
}

console.log(addDigits(38));
```

Comment: Число подменяется на сумму его цифр пока не станет однозначным.

Comment: @yolosora Я вот не пойму. Почему на 7-й строке 0, 1? Почему i - обнулился?

Comment: Потому что это вторая итерация цикла `while` в которой заново запустился цикл `for`

Comment: На всякий случай, вдруг пригодится, альтернативный вариант: `const addDigits = (num) => (num - 1) % 9 + 1;`

Comment: @Yaant рекурсию добавьте

Comment: @teran Э... а зачем?

Comment: @Yaant как такую короткую формулу вывел? xD

Comment: @Yaant пардоньте, не так понял :)

Comment: Все равно, как-то все запутанно тут.

Comment: @МаксимГончаров Так это известный факт, что если суммировать цифры числа до тех пор, пока не останется одна цифра, то получится остаток от деления исходного числа на 9, с той только разницей, что вместо 0 получается 9. :)